# How to save data for an anonymous user for a later use

Tags: java, spring

I need to build the following flow:

User uploads a file to the server (Spring 3.2) once successful, he needs to create an account and login in order access the processed file.

**Q:** How can I associate the file to a user with out him being logged in or even created?

I am using Spring 3.2 on the server and Angular 1.2.X

Comment: You can tie it to his session, but if he clears his cookies, you won't be able to tell anymore.  It's not clear if you'd consider this an answer.

Comment: you can also try with sessionStorage

Comment: This is a server side issue. You can either do it purely through sessions, or through sessions validated by some localStorage or some other browser API. Obviously without logging in it's fairly volatile and not particularly reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie. Tie the file to the cookie and use this subsequently identify them until they create their user. If they clear their cache then the link between them and the file is gone forever.

If you want to be a bit more resilient to browser cache clearing and work cross-browser then you could use a flash cookie but these are a bit of an old school hack these days..